# TensorFlow right loss function for Multi class and Multi label classification with ranking

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, classification, loss-function

I have 10 classes naming them 0 to 9

The output would look something like this

> [0.0, 0.75, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.875, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]

The above actual label is labeled in such a way that the 3rd index, which is also class 3 is Rank one and the 5th class is rank two, class 1 is ranked 3 and other classes are not relevant, so rank zero for the rest of them. In another word, the largest number has the highest rank, and so on. My main focus is on the ranks themselves, and I don't place importance on the specific values, such as 0.75 etc, that correspond to each rank.

**Approach 1 - Regression**

Last Dense layer with 10 neurons with `linear` activation function and loss as `keras.losses.MeanSquaredError()`.
My model is predicting mostly zero as that is the majority rank

**Approach 2 - Multiclass classification**

Last Dense layer with 10 neurons with `softmax` activation function and loss as `keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy()`. With this approach, we can sort normalized predictions and put a threshold, and below that threshold all rank zero. I am only getting Rank 1 rightly but other ranks are squashed down.

**Approach 3 - Linear + cosine similarity**
I am having `Linear` Activation function and `cosine similarity` as a loss function. Here I see most cosine similarity in training and validation while training is very good all are above 0.9 which means cosine similarity is doing good gradient decent but my downstream task of ranking is not working I just get the rank 1 and the last rank right rest all ranks are wrong.

I want to know what is the right activation function and loss function for this problem. Any custom loss function for ranking ?

Answer (score 1):

There is a [whole tensorflow module](https://www.tensorflow.org/ranking) devoted to ranking problems that you might draw inspiration from. For your examples, perhaps look at:

1. [Mean Squared Loss](https://www.tensorflow.org/ranking/api_docs/python/tfr/keras/losses/MeanSquaredLoss)
2. [Sigmoid Cross Entropy Loss](https://www.tensorflow.org/ranking/api_docs/python/tfr/keras/losses/SigmoidCrossEntropyLoss)

(there doesn't seem to be an analogous loss for your cosine similarity metric)

Answer (score 0):

When you use the softmax, you are forcing to select one label and also penalize the other. The assumption is that one of the labels are correct.
In you case, you have a multi-label multi-class classifications, you can remove the softmax and use the crossentropy for each label and loss would be the sum of the loss for all classes. if you have labels which should be ignored as well you can manage there.

Comment: Do you mean to use sigmoid in place of softmax and use a binary cross-entropy loss for all classes? If I am understanding right  The multilabel issue is solved but what about the rankings ?

Comment: by rank , do you mean that you do not care about the actual value, and only you want to be the order to be correct ? if so then you have to define a loss to consider that other wise kind of your labels represent that. you can define the output vector to be your ranked labels [3, 5 , 1, nan, nan. ...] and enforce the ranking like this,

Comment: yes exactly right I don't care about the actual values I only care about the suitable labels and their ranks. I have tried the approach which you mentioned using Regression predicting [3,5,1,0,0,..]. But not getting suitable results because of the same reason because most of them are 0 and the model is predicting 0s everywhere.